# BigQueryException: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am running a pyspark application locally, the application reads a table in BigQuery. Below are the details,

Spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --name "sampleApp" --master local[2] --deploy-mode client --packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.17.3 --verbose main.py
```

Pyspark code

```
    df = spark.read \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .load("projectName.datasetName.tableName")
```

I've set the environment variable to point to the path of the Secret JSON file in local.

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Pyspark version is

> pyspark==3.1.3

I've also tried using "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.25.0" package in spark-submit command.

I'm connected to VPN and I could see from the logs that all the dependencies are successfully downloaded, but I get the below error after submitting the spark job

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
> :
> **com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException**:
> **Remote host terminated the handshake**
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:106)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:268)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$17.call(BigQueryImpl.java:669)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$17.call(BigQueryImpl.java:666)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:665)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelationInternal(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:75)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:45)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: **Remote host terminated the
> handshake**
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1575)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1405)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:148)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
> at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:266)
> ... 25 more **Caused by**: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:167)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
> ... 37 more

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Seen to be the VPN, you need it to acces the internet?

Comment: Yes, I pull the packages from a private repository using "--repositories" options in spark-submit. I need to be on the VPN to be able to do it.

Comment: Closing this question as I was able to proceed further by adding a library **"io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.52.Final"** . but now getting another error which is tracked in this question [com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528964/com-google-cloud-spark-bigquery-repackaged-com-google-cloud-bigquery-bigqueryexc)