# com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Connection reset

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to read a GBQ table using the below approach,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, current_timestamp

def analyze(spark, config, query = None):
    df = spark.read \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .load("projectName.dataset.tablename")
    resultDf = df \
            .filter(col('colName')=='123') \
            .withColumn('processedTS',current_timestamp()) resultDf.write.mode('overwrite').option("header",True).csv("output/claims")
```

My spark-submit command is as follows,

```
spark-submit --name "ApplicationName" --master "local[2]" --deploy-mode "client" --jars jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.25.0.jar,jars/netty-tcnative-2.0.52.Final.jar --verbose main.py --jobName jobnameToRun
```

Environment variable is set to point to the location where the key Json is located,

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/PATH_TO_KEY/file.json
```

When i submit my application I get the below error,

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.load.
    : com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Connection reset
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:299)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:778)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:775)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:774)
            at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient.getTable(BigQueryClient.java:119)
            at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient.getReadTable(BigQueryClient.java:240)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelationInternal(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:76)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:45)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
            at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:188)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:151)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
            at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:297)
```

My system is uses Apple M1 Pro chip.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: i have similar issue in java client.

Comment: Hi @saravana ir, Are you still facing this issue? Which version of the Dataproc image are you using? Can you try supplying the jar as suggested in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#providing_the_connector_to_your_application)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Issue is with --jars you are submitting Please submit jar with full path like "--jars /fullpath/first.jar,/fullpath/second.jar"